# Is this construct correct? "This one something..."

Tags: grammaticality, determiners

After criticizing some whole category of blog posts as fake news, biased or undercover advertising, I was about to add:

> That being said, I must admit that *this one article* is quite interesting.

Is this construct correct?  Should I use "this article in particular" instead?

Comment: The construction *this one article* is just fine, and you can find similar examples all over the web. What made you think it was wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by _extrictly_?

Comment: I was trying to say that while posing as a news story, it is actually an advertising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction "this one article" is grammatically correct. Its use gives emphasis to that specific article.

Comment: Since I can't comment on things other than my own posts yet, I wanted to respond to JSBձոգչ's question. I think that since "this one" is normally used as a pronoun for whatever the subject is, the OP was questioning the use of adding the noun after the pronoun.